# Why order of quote character "'" in relation to '#1=' matters in circular lists?

Tags: lisp, circular-list

I am experimenting with circular lists and have written a flawed graph viewer. So when I try to draw 2 different graphs

```
(graph-viewer:graph '#1=(1 2 3 #1#) "a")
(graph-viewer:graph #1='(1 2 3 #1#) "b")
```

I get who different pictures with the latter version having a quote symbol included in the graph.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think how the [reader](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/23_.htm) does its job.

When it sees [`#1=`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dho.htm), it knows to store whatever comes next and re-use it on [`#1#`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhp.htm) - think about it as a "*binding*" for the "*variable 1*".

When it sees [`'<blah>`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dc.htm), it reads it as `(quote <blah>)`.

Thus, when it sees `'#1=(1 2 3 #1#)`, it reads it as

```
(quote (1 2 3 *))
       ^      |
       |      |
       +------+
```

(`quote` is *outside* of "binding of 1")

while `#1='(1 2 3 #1#)` is read as

```
(quote (1 2 3 *))
^             |
|             |
+-------------+
```

(`quote` is *inside* the "binding of 1").

The "arrow" in the pics above is the reference, i.e., `*` points along the arrow.

Comment: Excellent comment, but your answer indicates a cyclic infinite list. How do I wrap my mind around the leap from circular to the infinite list?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "infinite" list!

Comment: Haskellers say there is one. But I understand your point. I have built my assumptions on the incorrect concepts.

Comment: Lisp is not lazy. See edit, I replaced an apparent infinity with a visible circularity. Is it clearer now?

Comment: A sentence explaining your arrows going back may be helpful for someone.

Comment: Superb answer! Thank you very much.

Comment: Possibly accidentally, your link to http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhp.htm has helped me to find the answer to my first question in the comments.

Comment: No accident there ;-). CLHS is a _very good doc_. Really.